# How to delete an element from an object inside a ng-repeat?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, loops, object

I'm trying to delete several elements from an object but I'm getting an error, this object is inside of a ng-repeat.

**Error**:  *Duplicates in a repeater are not allowed. Use 'track by' expression to specify unique keys. Repeater: child in parent.beneficiaries, Duplicate key: undefined:undefined, Duplicate value: undefined*

I made a simple script on plukr: https://plnkr.co/edit/W2C9ML4dEgJzqj6JeqWC?p=preview

My Controller:

```
angular
  .module("myApp", [])
  .controller("myCtrl", myCtrl);

  function myCtrl(){
    var vm = this;

    vm.classification = [
        {
          "name": "Favoritos",
          "beneficiaries":[
            {
              "idE": "1",
              "type": "Beneficiarios",
              "name": "Alexander Bueno",
              "selected": false
            },
            {
              "idE": "2",
              "type": "Beneficiarios",
              "name": "Lorena Torrealba",
              "selected": false
            },
            {
              "idE": "3",
              "type": "Beneficiarios",
              "name": "Fabián Pernía",
              "selected": false
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "name": "Mis cuentas",
          "beneficiaries":[
            {
              "idE": "8",
              "type": "Cuentas",
              "name": "Corriente ...1234",
              "selected": false
            },
            {
              "idE": "9",
              "type": "Cuentas",
              "name": "Corriente ...9854",
              "selected": false
            },
            {
              "idE": "10",
              "type": "Cuentas",
              "name": "Ahorro ...9921",
              "selected": false
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "name": "Terceros",
          "beneficiaries":[
            {
              "idE": "4",
              "type": "Beneficiarios",
              "name": "Alexander Ramírez",
              "selected": false
            },
            {
              "idE": "5",
              "type": "Beneficiarios",
              "name": "Vicente Delgado",
              "selected": false
            },
            {
              "idE": "6",
              "type": "Beneficiarios",
              "name": "Alexis Rodríguez",
              "selected": false
            },
            {
              "idE": "7",
              "type": "Beneficiarios",
              "name": "Ignacio Bueno",
              "selected": false
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "name": "Tarjetas",
          "beneficiaries":[
            {
              "idE": "11",
              "name": "Visa ...6987",
              "selected": false
            },
            {
              "idE": "12",
              "name": "MasterCard ...7841",
              "selected": false
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "name": "Servicios",
          "beneficiaries":[
            {
              "idE": "13",
              "name": "Electricidad de Caracas",
              "selected": false
            },
            {
              "idE": "14",
              "name": "C.A.N.T.V",
              "selected": false
            }
          ]
        }
      ];

    //function to delete elements
    vm.deleteElements = function(){
      for(var parent in vm.classification){
        for(var child in vm.classification[parent].beneficiaries){
          //if an element is selected then it will be deleted
          if(vm.classification[parent].beneficiaries[child].selected)
            //this fails if there are more than one element
            delete vm.classification[parent].beneficiaries[child]
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

My view:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="myApp">

  <head>
    <link data-require="bootstrap-css@3.3.6" data-semver="3.3.6" rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.css" />
    <script data-require="angular.js@1.3.14" data-semver="1.3.14" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.14/angular.js"></script>
    <script data-require="jquery@*" data-semver="2.2.0" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script data-require="bootstrap@3.3.6" data-semver="3.3.6" src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body ng-controller="myCtrl as ctrl">
    <h1>Elements</h1>
    <a class="btn btn-danger" ng-click="ctrl.deleteElements();">Delete selected elements</a>

    <div class="well" ng-repeat="parent in ctrl.classification">
      <h3>{{parent.name}}</h3>
      <h5 ng-repeat="child in parent.beneficiaries">
        <input type="checkbox" ng-model="child.selected">{{child.name}}
      </h5>
    </div>

  </body>

</html>
```

So, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: `beneficiaries` is an array, so `child in vm.classification[parent].beneficiaries` is not correct, to begin with. Neither is `delete vm.classification[parent].beneficiaries[child]`.

Comment: Ok, what is the correct form to do that? If I add to that code `track by $index` inside `<h5 ng-repeat="child in parent.beneficiaries>` it works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `for ... in` to loop through an array is not correct, as it doesn't only consider the elements of an array. Neither is deleting an element of an array with `delete`. That doesn't change the size of an array.

A rather simple solution is to filter the array:

```
vm.deleteElements = function(){
  vm.classification.forEach(function (classification) {
    classification.beneficiaries = classification.beneficiaries.filter(function(beneficiary) {
      return !beneficiary.selected;
    });
  });
}
```

Or if the browser supports ES6:

```
vm.deleteElements = function(){
  vm.classification.forEach( classification =>
    classification.beneficiaries = classification.beneficiaries.filter(beneficiary => !beneficiary.selected)
  );
}
```

Comment: Great answer! Very clear! Thanks! It works very well!

Answer (score 1):

It's asking you to have some unique identifier for each item in `parent.beneficiaries`.  [Here is the Angular page on it](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat). If there is no unique id you can try `track by $index` or something like that.  But you should be able to use this:

`<h5 ng-repeat="child in parent.beneficiaries track by child.idE">`

Comment: with <h5 ng-repeat="child in parent.beneficiaries track by child.idE"> it does not work :(

Comment: It works if use track by $index! Thanks, but I have another question, how to delete the entries that were deleted?